# Find common values of two lists in R data table

Tags: r, arrays, data.table

I have a data table `test`:

| id | array1 | array2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) | c(3, 4, 5) |
| 2 | c(6, 7, 8, 9, 10) | c(6, 7, 0) |

```
> str(test)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  2 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ id    : num  1 2
 $ array1:List of 2
  ..$ : num  1 2 3 4 5
  ..$ : num  6 7 8 9 10
 $ array2:List of 2
  ..$ : num  3 4 5
  ..$ : num  6 7 0
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

**For each row** I want to find values which are common for `array1` and `array2` as well as to find values that are in `array1` but not in `array2`.

I tried using `setdiff()` and `intersect()` but got incorrect results:

```
test[, `:=` (diff = setdiff(array1, array2),
             common = intersect(array1, array2))]
```

| id | array1 | array2 | diff | common |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) | c(3, 4, 5) | c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) | NULL |
| 2 | c(6, 7, 8, 9, 10) | c(6, 7, 0) | c(6, 7, 8, 9, 10) | NULL |

**Expected output:**

| id | array1 | array2 | diff | common |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) | c(3, 4, 5) | c(1, 2) | c(3, 4, 5) |
| 2 | c(6, 7, 8, 9, 10) | c(6, 7, 0) | c(8, 9, 10) | c(6, 7) |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As these are `list`, use `Map` to loop over the `list` elements and apply the functions

```
library(data.table)
test[, c("diff", "common") := list(Map(setdiff, array1, array2), 
      Map(intersect, array1, array2))]
```

-output

```
> test
      id         array1 array2     diff common
   <int>         <list> <list>   <list> <list>
1:     1      1,2,3,4,5  3,4,5      1,2  3,4,5
2:     2  6, 7, 8, 9,10  6,7,0  8, 9,10    6,7
```

Or using a single `Map` with `transpose`

```
test[, c("diff", "common") := transpose(Map(function(x, y) 
      list(setdiff(x, y), intersect(x, y)), array1, array2))]
```

---

Or group by 'id' (assuming no duplicate 'id's) and extract (`[[1]]`) the first element

```
test[, c('diff', 'common') := .(.(setdiff(array1[[1]], 
        array2[[1]])), .(intersect(array1[[1]], array2[[1]]))), id]
```

#### data

```
test <- structure(list(id = 1:2, array1 = list(1:5, 6:10), 
   array2 = list(
    3:5, c(6L, 7L, 0L))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```